# How to create an index out of a file?

Tags: c++, seqan

Is is straightforward to create a index out of a String object for example :

```
typedef Index<CharString> TIndex;
TIndex index("How much wood would a woodchuck chuck?");
```

In my case, I have a large file. One obvious way is to load the text in the memory in a CharString object, then to create the index out of it, but is there a function in seqan to do it directly ? The documentation seems weird as it doesn't show constructors so I have no way to know if such constructor exists. Furthermore, my file is actually about DNA, so it would be a waste to load it normally (4 time more space) if a constructor of a `Index<DnaString>` existed.

Comment: If i'm not mistaken, there is little to no one on this site that knows how to work with seqan considering there is 9 questions tagged with it

Comment: @PasserBy I hesitated to ask the question but since the tag existed, I assumed that the relevant people must be subscribed to it...

Comment: There is 1 follower :)